# How to clone vb.net local object inside global "list of"

Tags: vb.net

I have a local object defined inside a private sub and I added this local object to a global "list of object".
Now the problem starts when I leave that local object scope( which is the private sub) since the local object will be out of scope and it will be deleted and this will cause the object will not be available any more inside the global "list of".

I can see that the "list of" is actually .add a reference to that object inside of its body when I do list.add(object).

My question:
How I can make the global "list of" to .add to its body a complete clone copy of that local object, so that I can access that list object globally?

Thank You

```
Public Class Form1


    Private myClass1 As ClassObject = Nothing

    Private listOfObjects As New List(Of ClassObject)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

       

        myClass1 = New ClassObject("aaa")
        MsgBox("object name: " & myClass1.FuncGetstrName()) 'this will display object's name

        listOfObjects.Add(myClass1)

        MsgBox("class name1: " & listOfObjects.Item(0).FuncGetstrName()) 'the object's still alive
        myClass1.Dispose()
        myClass1 = Nothing

        MsgBox("class name2: " & listOfObjects.Item(0).FuncGetstrName()) ' the object is not available                            
                                                                          'anymore

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't dispose the object and set it to Nothing if you intend to keep using it.

Comment: If you are dead set on the cloning, ClassObject  could implement [ICloneable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-7.0)  Although, if as per @topsail just don't destroy it in the private method

Comment: There's no such thing as a "local object". Objects don't have scope. Variables have scope. Your `myClass1` and `listOfObjects` variables are both members. Neither is a local variable and the word "global" is generally used to describe something that is accessible anywhere within your project, which neither of those are. They both have exactly the same scope.

Comment: Once you add the object to the list, it's in the list. That means that you can set `myClass1` to `Nothing` and still access the object via the list. Disposing the object makes no sense though. The whole point of disposing is to releases resources held by an object once you're finished using it. If you've added it to the list then presumably you want to use it again later, so don't dispose it.

Comment: Your question about cloning has got absolutely nothing at all to do with your variables, their scope or the list. The simple fact is that, if you want two distinct objects, you have to create the second object yourself. It will not happen by magic. You can create the new object and copy the data across or you can build the functionality to do that into the class itself and then call the appropriate method, but that is what has to be done either way. As suggested, if you want to build the functionality into the class then you should implement `ICloneable`.

Comment: If you do implement `ICloneable`, it may be as simple as calling `MemberwiseClone`. That will create a shallow copy of the object. If that's enough, that's all you have to do. If you need a deep copy though, you will have some extra work to do. You should read up on the difference between deep and shallow copies.